# Discord bot stops responding with no error after one minute

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a node.js discord bot, that was running fine until recently. (code avalible at https://github.com/ufo-studios/alienbot-2.0 ). There are no errors in the code, and it will still run console.logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What has changed recently?

Comment: I see you have a repo, so you can see the push history and check what changed.